# how to create django template tag for custom model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, templatetags

I'm new for django template tag. I am trying to display logged user payment_status and remaining_days on django html template. For this I wrote model and I don't know how to write template tag for this. Request your help on this.

```
models.py
class User_subscription(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    subscription_id = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscripted_date = models.DateTimeField()
    expired_date = models.DateTimeField()
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    payment_details = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

I want to display payment_status above in model and remaining_days = expired_date-subscripted_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#variables)

But ideally, you should have the variables sent from your Django view and then in the templates, have the variables in double quotes `{{ }}`

In your case, you will have

```
{{expired_date - subscripted_date}}
```

But I encourage you to check out the documentation